# Why is there difference in the DCT coefficients between matlab and libjpeg

Tags: matlab, jpeg, libjpeg, dct

I need to manipulate the DCT coefficients of a JPEG image, so I got the values using **libjpeg** and **matlab**. The problem is that I am getting different values.

I am working on the following image:
[image]

**libjpeg**

I have used `jpeg_read_coefficients` to get the virtual array and then iterate over it and printed the DCT values, for the first array and first dct block I got the following values:

9 8 10 6 3 1 1 0 -6 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 6 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

This is the coefficients in straight order as said in the documentation.

**Matlab**

In order to get the coefficients I read the image and ran `dct2` function on its first 8X8 block:

```
A = imread('test2.jpg');
dct2(A(1:8,1:8,1));
```

and came up with the following values(For the RGB color space):

404.7500   -2.5251   15.1704   18.4835   14.7500    8.0465   10.4933    1.6169
  -50.4069    0.4634    3.2328   -0.3498   -0.6745    0.9465    0.4599    0.5694
   16.0546   -1.7709   -3.3624   -0.0164    0.2310   -0.9791   -0.1250   -1.0587
   14.7190    0.9301   -0.0935    0.2866   -0.5779   -0.2573    1.2260    0.1872
   15.5000    0.4715   -1.2505   -0.9827   -0.0000    0.1208    0.2474    1.4739
    9.4079    0.5931   -0.3263    0.0659    0.4536    0.2866   -0.3059    0.3997
   10.6682    0.2906    0.1250   -0.6038   -0.0957   -0.0583   -0.8876   -1.2576
    0.7863   -0.1074   -0.7177   -0.4161    0.9382   -0.6301   -0.7815    0.4634

And those values for YCbCr color space:

1.0e+03 *(
    1.0305    0.0142    0.0168    0.0151    0.0130    0.0071    0.0085    0.0003
   -0.0100    0.0002    0.0029   -0.0001   -0.0002    0.0006   -0.0004   -0.0005
    0.0151   -0.0024   -0.0025   -0.0000         0   -0.0002   -0.0005   -0.0000
    0.0132   -0.0000   -0.0004   -0.0007   -0.0008   -0.0008   -0.0001    0.0011
    0.0140   -0.0004    0.0003   -0.0010    0.0005   -0.0002    0.0001   -0.0004
    0.0086    0.0001   -0.0000    0.0002    0.0004    0.0004   -0.0003    0.0001
    0.0078   -0.0002   -0.0005   -0.0000         0   -0.0003   -0.0000   -0.0005
    0.0003   -0.0000   -0.0003    0.0003    0.0012   -0.0003   -0.0002   -0.0005)

My guess, since I couldn't approve it with the libjpeg documentation, is that the coefficients are for the YCbCr space.
I understand that the values in the libjpeg are after quantization error and the first DC component is decoded by the difference so lets take a look at the second component, its quantization constant is 2 (retrieved with hex dump from the raw data) so the difference can be at most 2.

The computed DCT value for the second coefficient in the Matlab calculation is 14.2 while in the raw image its 8. And I cant figure out what I have done wrong, any ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The DCT is done on the YCbCr colour space, not the RGB colour space as you have suspected.  You also need to realize that there is probably a 4:2:0 subsampling of the chroma components in comparison to the luminance.  I don't really know what `libjpeg` is doing to give you a more authoritative answer, but that's something I can suggest for now.

Comment: This is a nice idea, I will try to check it out! thanks

Comment: Also, JPEG stores the values in zigzag order and the JPEG values you have above look like they have been quantized.

Comment: @user3344003 - Good point! I forgot about that.

Comment: Please tell me you have the code to iterate the Coefficients value returned by read_coefficients, absolutely no example anywhere i have found online does this properly accounting for edge cases and different sample factors, im tearing my hair out trying to just make sure i have actually iterated over every single value in the coefficients array returned, but there is no way to ensure you have since there are no sizes for any of the arrays and i cant find whether or not libjpeg is padding a load of rubbish on the end of any of the arrays either